# How can i align the highchart legend pagination to right or left side of the legends?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I wanted to move the legend pagination to the right or left side of the legends

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Manikandan_kannan/0mu2nLqh/1/)

```
  "legend":{
  "enabled":true,
  "maxHeight":50,
  "itemMarginTop":5,
  "navigation":{
     "activeColor":"#1d4659",
     "animation":true,
     "inactiveColor":"rgba(29, 70, 89, 0.5)"
  }
```

[Sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeNg5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `scroll` method and position the arrows according to your requirements:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'scroll', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        this.nav.attr({
            translateY: 10,
            translateX: 390
        });
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/25ahwq1k/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts